# Отсутствует перевод moderator-agreement

Tags: предложение, статус-отложено, локализация, модерация

Не переведена страница [Соглашение модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement).

Если это юридически допустимо, то надо бы перевести.

Копирую сюда текущий текст:

> ### Moderator Agreement
>
> In order to access the ♦ moderator functions, our [community moderators](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) must review and accept the following terms:
>
> ### The agreement
>
> I acknowledge and agree that as a moderator for Stack Exchange Inc.
>
> - i. I will abide by the then-current [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) of Stack Overflow на русском, and other moderator policies made available to me,
> - ii. I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially personally-identifying information about Stack Overflow на русском users and that in connection with such access
> - a. I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current [Privacy Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) of Stack Overflow на русском,
> - b. I will not disclose this information to anyone,
> - c. I will not store or copy this information and
> - d. I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Stack Overflow на русском moderator for the benefit of Stack Overflow на русском.
>
> I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator to Stack Overflow на русском and I am not an employee, agent or representative of Stack Exchange Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Exchange Inc. in any manner. Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the right to terminate my privileges as a moderator at any time without warning.

Comment: Пока что ситуация такая. Эта страница несет в себе юридическую силу, просто так перевести её не получится, так как необходимо консультироваться с юристом. На Transifex она доступна не будет. Сейчас идет обсуждение, каким образом проще решить проблему.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: есть ли новости по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Перевел. Надеюсь, скоро оно мне пригодится )

Upd: не пригодилось, принимал непереведённый текст.

---

> ### Moderator Agreement

### Соглашение Модератора

> In order to access the ♦ moderator functions, our [community moderators](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) must review and accept the following terms:

Чтобы получить доступ к полномочиям ♦ модератора, наши [избранные сообществом модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) должны изучить и принять следующие обязательства:

> ### The agreement

### Соглашение

> I acknowledge and agree that as a moderator for Stack Exchange Inc.

Я понимаю и соглашаюсь, что как модератор Stack Exchange Inc.

> - i. I will abide by the then-current [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) of Stack Overflow на русском, and other moderator policies made available to me,

i. Я буду следовать текущему [Соглашению об Оказании Услуг (Terms of Service)](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) Stack Overflow на русском и другим правилам для модераторов, которые будут мне предоставлены,

> - ii. I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially personally-identifying information about Stack Overflow на русском users and that in connection with such access

ii. Я понимаю, что я получу доступ к информации, которая может быть использована для идентификации пользователей Stack Overflow на русском, и что имея такой доступ

> - a. I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current [Privacy Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) of Stack Overflow на русском,

a. Я буду использовать полученную информацию исключительно в соответствии с действующей в данный момент [Политикой Конфиденциальности (Privacy Policy)](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) Stack Overflow на русском,

> - b. I will not disclose this information to anyone,

b. Я не буду раскрывать эту информацию кому-либо,

> - c. I will not store or copy this information and

c. Я не буду сохранять или копировать эту информацию, и

> - d. I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Stack Overflow на русском moderator for the benefit of Stack Overflow на русском.

d. Я буду использовать эту информацию исключительно в целях осуществления своих функций модератора Stack Overflow на русском и во благо Stack Overflow на русском.

> I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator to Stack Overflow на русском and I am not an employee, agent or representative of Stack Exchange Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Exchange Inc. in any manner. Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the right to terminate my privileges as a moderator at any time without warning.

Я признаю и соглашаюсь с тем, что я являюсь независимым и добровольным модератором Stack Overflow на русском, и я не являюсь сотрудником, агентом или представителем Stack Exchange Inc. и не имею полномочий связывать Stack Exchange Inc. какими-либо обязательствами. Stack Exchange Inc. обладает правом отозвать мои права модератора в любой момент без уведомления.