# Появился фанат/фанатка. Что делать?

Tags: поддержка, голоса-за

Мне второй раз кто-то ставит кучу лойсов.
Потом эти лойсы удаляются, так как поставлены одним человеком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за таких голосований/съёмов баллов репутации у меня начались проблемы.

Моя мама и друзья обвиняют меня в наличии виртуала/виртуалов на СО.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно ли что-то с этим сделать?

Как защититься от фанатов?

P.S. Значок "Академик", за 200 баллов репутации в день - не аннулировался после съёма баллов. Таким образом, видимо, можно и значок "Легенда" заработать, несмотря на то, что баллы сняли.

Comment: ничего. расслабьтесь и получайте удовольствие.

Comment: Пригласите в кино, если ваш фанат с вами разных полов, и на пиво, если одного.

Comment: @VladD проблема в том, что я не знаю кто это. По-этому, для окружающих всё выглядит, так, если бы у меня был виртуал.

Comment: @MAXOPKA: Из алгоритмов могу предложить полный перебор. Без оптимизации у вас около трёх с половиной миллиардов вариантов.

Comment: @VladD а может при достижении определенного размера репутации появится возможность смотреть, кто голосовал?

Comment: @MAXOPKA: 69032 балла для этого всё ещё недостаточно, дальше не знаю.

Comment: @VladD хм. То есть получается, что если один человек очень много голосовал за ответы другого человека, то откат голосов происходит автоматически?

Comment: Со стороны админов было бы неэтично выдавать вам голосующего за вас, даже если они и видят его. У голосующего есть обоснованное ожидание анонимности.

Comment: @MAXOPKA: Да. Это автоматическая функциональность системы, против серийных плюсов и минусов.

Comment: Надеюсь, что он/она это прочитает, перед тем как в следующий раз поставить много лойсов подряд.

Comment: что такое "лойсы"? похоже на пейсы, но как вам их ставят?

Comment: @Grundy "лойс" - это "+1", одобрение. "-1" - "дизлойс"

Comment: @Grundy: Это искажённое «лайк».

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Моя мама и друзья обвиняют меня в наличии виртуала/виртуалов на СО.

30 декабря некий участник отдал 19 голосов за ваши ответы и 31 декабря эти голоса откатились системой. Я сравнил ваши учетные записи по нескольким объективным критериям: ни один из них не указывает на то, что учетная запись принадлежит вам и используется для накрутки. Можете передать это родным.

UPD: Пару дней назад ситуация повторилась с тем же результатом. Снова нет подозрений на накрутку.

> Можно ли что-то с этим сделать?

Разве что написать на странице учетной записи, что если кто-то хочет подарить вам много репутации, то пусть голосует понемногу и за все хорошие ответы, а не только ваши.

> Как защитится от фанатов?

Вам это не вредит. Откат голосов может иметь негативные последствия только для голосующего (а может и не иметь).

> а может при достижении определенного размера репутации появится возможность смотреть, кто голосовал?

Для этого нужен как минимум ♦; причём [соглашение модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2116/181472) прямо запрещает использовать эту возможность для того, чтобы пригласить человека в кино или на пиво. Только для модерации. Вот такая печаль.

Comment: Сказано «лойсы» — сделано!

Comment: "причём соглашение модератора прямо запрещает использовать эту возможность для того, чтобы пригласить человека в кино или на пиво" - а если никому не сказать о том, что пригласил из-за голосов?

Comment: @Max: вот мы сходим в кино, понравимся друг другу, поженимся, нарожаем детей, те внуков. А потом вдруг правда выяснится. И что делать? )

Comment: @nick-volynkin Ну, если об этом не узнает stackoverflow, то я думаю, ничего страшного. А если фанат(ка) - модератор, то может быть забанит нарушителя, вряд ли что-то более серьезное :)

Answer (score 7):

**Ничего не делайте. Сохраняйте курс и просто забудьте об этом происшествии.**

Если у вас появляются фанаты, то это скорее хорошо, значит, ваши ответы приносят очень много пользы хотя бы отдельным личностям.

#### У StackOverflow нет интереса мешать созданию подобных ситуаций.

...при условии, что возможные вредные последствия ликвидированы:

- `[V]` Крупные партии голосов в одном и том же направлении обнаруживаются и отменяются автоматически. Можете смело парировать этим обвинения о владении "виртуалами" в свой адрес, т. к. вы же достаточно умны, чтобы эту систему не злить, верно? `;)`
- `[V]` Значок "Академик" никак не влияет на ваши привилегии и минимально влияет на вашу привлекательность в роли модератора на выборах, так что механически его существование для вас ничего не меняет.

[А отзывать значки в сети StackExchange не принято](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258768/2076787). Они всё равно мало о чём говорят.

Answer (score 5):

Про поклонников всё расписали, повторяться не буду. Лишь прокомментирую ваши опасения по поводу значков.

> P.S. Значок "Академик", за 200 баллов репутации в день - не аннулировался после съёма баллов.

Это известный баг, но на него забили болт (это бронзовый значок, на его получение всем наплевать). Наслаждайтесь халявой.

> Таким образом, видимо, можно и значок "Легенда" заработать, несмотря на то, что баллы сняли.

Не получится. Каждые сутки после набега поклонников голоса будут сниматься, а счётчик на Легенде приходить в исходное состояние. То есть если у вас "5 академиков", то набеги поклонников приведут к дёрганию счётчика между 5 и 6.

Comment: Не совсем верно - `Академик` присуждается единожды. И все следующие 200+ репы в день лишь инкременируют счётчик `Легенды`. На собственном опыте выяснил - чуть было не начал скандал в чате, когда не получил 2-ого и 3-го `Академика` =)

Comment: Не столько баг, сколько "дизайн" или его отсутствие: нет никакого автоматического процесса, _забирающего_ стандартные значки. (В отличие от значков по меткам.)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Гм, кавычку неправильно поставил. Передвинул.