# Нет перевода при отправке ответа без регистрации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не будучи зарегистрированным (можно открыть в режиме инкогнито) можно отвечать на вопросы. Однако, в этом случае присутствует непереведенный текст:

> By clicking "Отправить ответ", you acknowledge that you have read our updated terms of service, privacy policy and cookie policy, and that your continued use of the website is subject to these policies.

> [image: картинка]

Comment: возможно [к GDPR относится](https://xkcd.com/1998/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неожиданно обнаружил проблемную строку в Transifex и сделал следующий перевод:

> Нажимая «$submitButtonText$», вы подтверждаете, что прочитали наши обновлённые $tosLinkStart$пользовательское соглашение$tosLinkEnd$, $privacyLinkStart$политику конфиденциальности$privacyLinkEnd$ и $cookieLinkStart$политику о cookie$cookieLinkEnd$, и что вы продолжаете использование сайта в соответствии с этими положениями.

Перевод добавлен:

> [image: На сайте]

Answer (score 5):

### И тем не менее, перевод этой надписи необходим.

Ведь, на секундочку, вся идея "Stack Overflow на русском" в том, чтобы сделать "Stack Overflow" доступнее для тех, кому общение русском языке комфортнее.

Если "юридически[е] аспект[ы] ситуации" требуют наличия этой надписи на английском, существование этой надписи **также и на русском (рядом)** никак им не помешает. В идеале, заодно и отметить, что на английском этот пассаж присутствует не просто так.

---

Есть, конечно, более крупная проблема, это отсутствие перевода на русский язык всех этих соглашений и политик. Но по серьёзности эта проблема заметно меньше, ведь они размещены на англоязычном ресурсе, где уже русский язык будет смотреться странно; а политики одинаковые для всей сети.

Совсем в идеале, неплохо бы иметь приближённые переводы политик на русский язык с примечанием об отсутствии юридической силы у *перевода*, в отличие от *оригинала*.

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказывают мои коллеги, ответ — нет, переводиться данная строка не будет, в связи с юридическими аспектами ситуации.

Comment: Странно, что на MSE до сих пор не ответили на [похожую ситуацию](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310569/339911). Ну и я ещё мог понять [отсутствие перевода в соглашении для модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217), т.к. это затрагивает небольшой круг лиц, но чтобы любому незарегистрированного на ruSO показывать смесь русского и английского текстов... Кстати, а не стоит ли сменить тогда [meta-tag:статус-отложено] на вопросе о соглашении?

Comment: @alexolut Не уверен. В следствии развития «Команд», в будущем может быть что угодно.

Comment: Что за "Команды"?

Comment: Новый штуковина на сайте: https://stackoverflow.com/teams

Comment: Это то, что раньше называлось "Channels"?

Comment: @alexolut Я думаю, что именно так и есть.

Comment: Переводиться с заменой может и нет, а что на счёт перевода рядом? Ну серьёзно, это очень странная ситуация для русскоязычного сайта.