# Не переведено сообщение о минимальном возрасте модераторов

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

> All moderators are required to be 18 years old or older. If you are under 18, email Community Managers so we can begin the process of removing your diamond.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Написал коллективное письмо от имени действующих модераторов.

Comment: Кажется, этой строки нет в Transifex, надо писать на MSE, чтоб добавили.

Comment: А ты что уходишь из модераторов? (((

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, я? С чего бы вдруг? о_О

Comment: Фухххххххxxx ;)

Comment: `so we can begin the process of removing your diamond` — вот эта строчка навела на мысль ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, это общее уведомление - просто правило ввели, что модератором можно быть только с 18 лет.

Comment: Возможно, что [так-задумано] на основании отсутствия перевода всего [модераторского соглашения.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217)