# Отсутствие перевода справки о сотрудниках компании

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Отсутствует перевод на странице  'Репутация и модерация' на некоторых ссылках, а также и в содержимом этих ссылок(*справка - Репутация и модерация*)

> [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

> [Moderator Agreement policies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies)

Comment: По мод.соглашению [старая история](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217). А вот по сотрудникам, похоже, раньше не было пунктика. Поэтому предлагаю на этом сделать акцент.