# Опечатки и отсутствие переводов

Tags: дефект, локализация

1. Даже в этом вопросе можно обнаружить слово Modified.
2. Статья в справке полностью на английском языке, но на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/staff).
3. Опечатка в слове "откл***о***няется" (*откла́няется* неуместно) в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags).

| [image: 1] | [image: 2] | [image: 3] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Рис. 1. Слово в верхней части любого вопроса | Рис. 2. Целая статья на английском | Рис. 3. Опечатка в справке |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил доступный через traducir перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17687

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2022.4.14.41981

Переводы страниц справки делаются отдельно через менеджера сообщества модераторами, через traducir они недоступны.

Про сотрудников уже ранее публиковали вопрос: [Отсутствие перевода справки о сотрудниках компании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11690/176217)