# Нет перевода справки "DMCA Takedowns"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Справка про DMCA Takedowns требует перевода:

[What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown)

Comment: Про [модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217) и [сотрудников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11690/176217) есть. Можно только про DMCA оставить.