# Как следует переводить термин "Copyright Policy"?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка, термины

Термин встречается в англоязычной справке и ссылается на подзаголовок в наших [Условиях использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#copyright) (которые, не переведены):

> 11. Copyright policy

Comment: Я не думаю, что эти условия вообще будут переводиться. То, что они доступны по ссылке с базой на ruSO, совершенно не значит, что они как-то кастомизируются. Ну и, например, Модераторское соглашение [не планируется переводить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217), так как это юридический документ. Это даже не раздел "Help" (Справка), а раздел "Legal". Так что метка [meta-tag:справка] под вопросом тоже "под вопросом".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Этот термин встречается на странице справки про модераторское соглашение. Эту страницу мы можем перевести

Comment: На какой странице? Можно ссылку?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ошибся, на странице про DMCA: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12621/339283

Comment: Надо тогда на эту страницу справки и сослаться в вопросе, справка по большому счёту должна быть переведена, но может опять всплывёт какая-то особенность как и с модераторским соглашением. Поэтому я бы может рекомендовал задать вопрос на MSE для уточнения, можно ли иметь на сайте переведённый вариант или нет. Пока что везде (pt, es, ja) она тоже на английском.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Принятый перевод:

> Политика авторских прав

Отклонённые варианты:

- Политика в отношении авторских прав

Comment: "Авторское право" не применяется в единственном числе, стоит поправить.

Comment: Это звучит как будто "авторские права" - это что-то одушевленное, имеющее какую-то политику. "в отношении авторских прав" звучит лучше.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Короткий вариант может быть удобнее в использовании

Answer (score 3):

Я нашёл такой пример на сайте G20. В [английской версии](https://www.g20.org/en/copyright-policy/) те самые:

> Copyright policy

В [русскоязычной](https://www.g20.org/ru/copyright-policy/):

> Политика в области авторского права

Мне кажется, что этот источник достаточно авторитетный, чтобы можно было доверять качеству перевода.