# Перевод страницы справки "What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Оригинальная страница: [What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown)

Answer (score 2):

## Что такое уведомление о нарушении DMCA и почему моё сообщение было удалено?

---

### Что такое уведомление о нарушении DMCA?

[Закон об авторском праве в цифровую эпоху (DMCA)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) (англ. Digital Millennium Copyright Act) — это закон Соединённых Штатов об авторском праве, который соблюдает Stack Exchange. Согласно закону, компания должна удалить защищённый авторским правом контент, который находится на нашей платформе и нарушает чьё-либо авторское право. Уведомление о нарушении DMCA — это то, как правообладатели информируют нас о существовании авторского права на свой контент.

### Почему моё сообщение было удалено?

Компания Stack Exchange должна выполнять законные и должным образом подписанные запросы на удаление. Если ваше сообщение было удалено с уведомлением DMCA, это значит, что мы получили такое уведомление и обработали его соответствующим образом.

### Может ли удалённое сообщение быть восстановлено?

Если вы считаете, что сообщение было удалено по ошибке и что не нарушает авторское право, вы можете направить встречное уведомление о нарушении DMCA. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с нашей [политикой в отношении авторских прав](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#copyright) для получения более подробной информации. Stack Exchange не является юридической фирмой и не может дать вам юридическую консультацию относительно обоснованности подачи встречного уведомления. Пожалуйста, имейте в виду, что это может повлечь за собой юридические риски. Вот причины, по которым встречное уведомление будет действительным:

- Использование вами содержимого, защищённого авторским правом,
  подпадает под действие правил добросовестного использования. Это
  очень субъективно, и необходимо проявлять осторожность, если вы
  полагаетесь только на это основание.
- На самом деле авторское право на содержимое не распространяется.
- Содержимое принадлежит кому-то другому, а не уведомляющей стороне.

Вот что нам потребуется от вас, чтобы отправить встречное уведомление:

- Идентификация, включая конкретные URL-адреса материалов, которые
  корпорация Stack Exchange удалила или к которым Stack Exchange отключила доступ.
- Имя пользователя, адрес, номер телефона и адрес электронной почты.
- Заявление о том, что пользователь согласен с юрисдикцией Федерального
  окружного суда судебного округа, в котором находится ваш адрес (или
  округа Нью-Йорк, штат Нью-Йорк, если ваш адрес находится за пределами
  Соединённых Штатов), и что пользователь примет процессуальные услуги
  от лица, предоставившего уведомление в соответствии с подразделом
  (c)(1)(C) или агентом такого лица.
- Следующее заявление: «Я клянусь, под страхом наказания за
  лжесвидетельство, что у меня есть добросовестное убеждение в том, что
  материал был удалён или отключён в результате ошибки или неверной
  идентификации материала, подлежащего удалению или отключению».
- Физическая или электронная подпись пользователя.

Вы можете отправить нам встречное уведомление через страницу [связаться с нами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact), выбрав опцию «Я хочу отправить Уведомление DMCA или встречный иск».

Comment: "Что такое уведомление DMCA и почему мой вклад был удалён?
" - может так: "Что такое уведомление DMCA и почему моё сообщение было удалено?"

Comment: И если это черновик, то почему бы не сделать сообщение общим?

Comment: @Зонтик Не понимаю, как это взаимосвязано

Comment: Ну это можно сделать как минимум для того, чтобы участники сообщества могли улучшить перевод.

Comment: @Зонтик Любой участник и так может его улучшить, предложив правку

Comment: Нет, не любой. На мете правки-предложения для сообщений, которые не являются общими, запрещены: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS86O.png

Comment: То есть пользователи с репутацией > 2k ничего изменить не могут =(